# getting a value from a specific child node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an html and using htmlagilitypack with c#. I need to get a specific child node value. I need to get the text of the child "strong/em" in the html. how can i get it?

```html
<div id="top3">
       <li> February  1, 2016&#58; 
         <a target="_blank" href="test1.html"> 
            <strong> 
               <em>test1</em></strong>
          </a>

         <br><strong>desc1</strong></li>

<li> February  2, 2016&#58; 
         <a target="_blank" href="test2.html"> 
            <strong> 
               <em>test2</em></strong>
          </a>

         <br><strong>desc2</strong></li>

        </div>
```

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='top3']//li"))
{                     
     sb.Append("<p'>" + node.SelectSingleNode("a[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]").InnerText + "</p>");
     linkNode = node.SelectSingleNode("a[1]");
     sb.Append("<p class='event'><a href='" + linkNode.Attributes["href"].Value + "'>" +  

        //**********Need to have text from  /strong/em/  here *********

     + "</a></p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of `strong/em` by using simple XPath relative to the selected `<a>` element, like so :

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='top3']//li"))
{ 
    .....
    linkNode = node.SelectSingleNode("a[1]");
    var em = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("strong/em").InnerText;
    //TODO: use `em` value according to your need :
    .....
}
```

Short demo here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/r49Luk

You have demonstrated the use of slightly more complex XPath expressions in the code snippet posted, so I kinda wonder why this question arised...